# Creating an Array of Arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, data-structures, julia

I'm trying to create an array of arrays of a special type in Julia.

For example, I want to create a list that saves lists (arrays) of integer values.

I need to know how to:

1. Initialize an (empty) list for the arrays
2. Use `append!`/`push!` to add an array of a specific data structure (in this case integer arrays) to the list

I think this is a very easy question (and is probably answered somewhere in the documentation), but my previous research confuses me more and more.

Is there a difference between:

```
List = Int64[]
```

and

```
List = Array{Int64,1}
```

Something like this does not work for me:

```
ListOfList = Int64[Int64]
ListOfList = Array{Int64[],1}
ListOfList = Array{Array{Int64,1},1}
```

Comment: `listOfList = Array{Any,1}`, so how can I save integer arrays in this object? `e = [1,2,3,4]` <br> `append!(listOfList,e)` does not work

Comment: Yes, that does not work, too.

Comment: I would also like to use other data structures, not just integers. So if  `listOfList[1] = [0, 1, 2, 3]`would work, it doesnt solves my problem all in all. But it does not work, because the object is "just initialized", so append/push operation or indexing does not work

Comment: In Java i would write `ArrayList<MyClass> ListOfList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();` And after this initialization and decleration i can add MyClass elements

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I would guess OP is trying to avoid arrays of dimension greater than 1 in order to use the `push!` and `append!` functions (which will only work on vectors).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can construct your array of arrays like so:

```matlab
# Initialize an array that can contain any values
listOfLists = Any[]

# Push some arrays into the array
push!(listOfLists, [1, 2, 3])
push!(listOfLists, [4, 5])
push!(listOfLists, ["Julia", "rocks"])

# You now have an array containing arrays
listOfLists
# 3-element Array{Any,1}:
#  [1,2,3]                     
#  [4,5]                       
#  ASCIIString["Julia","rocks"]
```

To answer your question regarding the difference in initialization, consider the following.

```matlab
List = Int64[]
typeof(List)
# Array{Int64,1}

List = Array{Int64,1}
typeof(List)
# DataType
```

The former is actually initializing `List` to be a 1-dimensional array containing integer values, whereas the latter is setting `List` to be the *type* `Array{Int64,1}`.