# In Julia, how do you create an array of unique, empty mutable objects?

Tags: arrays, julia

The [helpstring for `fill`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/array.jl#L389), says:

```
help?> fill
search: fill fill! finally findall filter filter! filesize filemode FileSyntax FileSchema isfile CSVFile @__FILE__ CSVFileSyntax fieldtype fieldname

  fill(x, dims)

  Create an array filled with the value x. For example, fill(1.0, (5,5)) returns a 5×5 array of floats, with each element initialized to 1.0.

...

  If x is an object reference, all elements will refer to the same object. fill(Foo(), dims) will return an array filled with the result of evaluating
  Foo() once.
```

Note that last paragraph:

> If `x` is an object reference, all elements will refer to the same object. `fill(Foo(),
>   dims)` will return an array filled with the result of evaluating `Foo()` once.

So I was wondering, how *does* one construct an Array of `n` unique objects?

E.g. say I want an array of 3 empty, separate dictionaries.

---

Related: [Creating an Array of Arrays in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626713/creating-an-array-of-arrays-in-julia)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best I can come up with is to use a comprehension:

```
julia> ds = [Dict() for _ in 1:3]
2-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()
```

Is this the best approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here are two alternatives I can think of:

```
julia> map(_ -> Dict(), 1:3)
3-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()

julia> (_ -> Dict()).(1:3)
3-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()
```

but in practice I use a comprehension as you have proposed.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs

> fill(Foo(), dims) will return an array filled with the result of
>   evaluating Foo() once

So this happen and that's exactly what you want to avoid:

```
julia> a = fill(Dict(), 4)
4-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()

julia> a[1]["foo"] = :bar
:bar

julia> a
4-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 Dict("foo" => :bar)
 Dict("foo" => :bar)
 Dict("foo" => :bar)
 Dict("foo" => :bar)
```

So the way to go is to use list comprehension as stated in discourse:

```
julia> a = [Dict() for i in 1:4]
4-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()

julia> a[1]["foo"] = :bar
:bar

julia> a
4-element Array{Dict{Any,Any},1}:
 Dict("foo" => :bar)
 Dict()
 Dict()
 Dict()
```

Related question:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/initialize-array-of-arrays/11610/4

Comment: Ah, this is what I was referring to in the last paragraph of the docs above. The reason is that what you've written there produces an array with 4 **references** to the _same Dict object!_ So if you add a pair to one of them, it would get added to all of them, which is not what i want.

Comment: The undef would be fine, but then I still need to manually set them all, which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: sorry, @NHDaly I have rewritten my answer as I didn't understand the problem.